# Silverlight 5: Terrible Performance Issues with DropShadowEffect

Tags: silverlight, performance, effect

Environment Info:

> Windows 7 64bit SP1
>
> 6GB Memory
>
> Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400S CPU @ 2.50GHz (4 cores)
>
> Silverlight 5

I have very terrible performance issues with `DropShadowEffect` in Silerlight.

I created a minimized demo for it:
http://www.peterlee.com.cn/public/ShadowEffectTestDemo/ShadowEffectTestTestPage.html

Click the button `Zoom` to try to zoom the canvas (with a Star shape with `DropShadowEffect`).  You will find that when the `Zoom = 64`, your CPU and memory are very crazy.

But, if you remove the `DropShadowEffect` by clicking the `Remove Effect` button, and then zoom it, everything is okay.

However, if we use a `TextBlock` with `DropShadowEffect`, everything is fine.  You can try it by clicking the "Use TextBlock` button.

I don't know what Silverlight is dealing with the TextBlock and my customized Star shape for the `DropShadowEffect`.

Please help me out.  Thanks.

**UPDATE**:
According to the replies:

I also tried it in Release mode (now the sample demo link was built in Release mode);

I also added GPA acceleration suggested by ChrisF:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
  <param name="EnableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />
  <param name="source" value="ShadowEffectTest.xap"/>
  <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
  <param name="background" value="white" />
  <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
  <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
  <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration:none">
     <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
  </a>
</object>
```

Here is the UPDATED code

MainPage.xmal:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ShadowEffectTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <Button x:Name="btnZoom" Width="75" Height="23" Content="Zoom"
                Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                Click="btnZoom_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnRemoveEffect" Width="100" Height="23" Content="Remove Effect"
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                Click="btnRemoveEffect_Click"/>
        
        <Button x:Name="btnUseTextBlock" Width="120" Height="23" Content="Use TextBlock"
                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                Click="btnUseTextBlock_Click" />

        <Canvas x:Name="mainCanvas" Width="200" Height="150" Background="LightBlue"
                Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;

namespace ShadowEffectTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

// These are the points for a Star shape
            List<Point> points = new List<Point>()
            {
                new Point(0, 36.3634469292486),
                new Point(-12.3606797688474, 43.2188191057189),
                new Point(-24.7213595376948, 50.0741912821893),
                new Point(-37.0820393065422, 56.9295634586596),
                new Point(-34.4313595448175, 42.9654855127096),
                new Point(-31.7806797830927, 29.0014075667595),
                new Point(-29.130000021368, 15.0373296208095),
                new Point(-39.4200000080385, 5.31010468057062),
                new Point(-49.709999994709, -4.41712025966827),
                new Point(-59.9999999813794, -14.1443451999072),
                new Point(-46.0011100186002, -15.919247828416),
                new Point(-32.002220055821, -17.694150456925),
                new Point(-18.0033300930418, -19.4690530854338),
                new Point(-12.0022200620278, -32.3361808961241),
                new Point(-6.00111003101392, -45.2033087068145),
                new Point(0, -58.0704365175048),
                new Point(6.00111003101392, -45.2033087068145),
                new Point(12.0022200620278, -32.3361808961241),
                new Point(18.0033300930418, -19.4690530854338),
                new Point(32.002220055821, -17.694150456925),
                new Point(46.0011100186002, -15.919247828416),
                new Point(59.9999999813794, -14.1443451999072),
                new Point(49.709999994709, -4.41712025966827),
                new Point(39.4200000080385, 5.31010468057062),
                new Point(29.130000021368, 15.0373296208095),
                new Point(31.7806797830927, 29.0014075667595),
                new Point(34.4313595448175, 42.9654855127096),
                new Point(37.0820393065422, 56.9295634586596),
                new Point(24.7213595376948, 50.0741912821893),
                new Point(12.3606797688474, 43.2188191057189),
                new Point(0, 36.3634469292486)
            };

            uie = RenderBezier(points);

// This the evil for the performance issues (crazy memory and CPU)
            uie.Effect = ShadowEffect;
            uie.CacheMode = new BitmapCache();

            uie.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 25.0);
            uie.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 25.0);

            mainCanvas.Children.Add(uie);
        }
        private UIElement uie = null;

        public Path RenderBezier(List<Point> ctrlPoints, List<List<Point>> innersCtrlPoints = null)
        {
            // Step 0: Merge ctrlPoints lists
            List<List<Point>> ctrlPointsLists;
            if (innersCtrlPoints == null)
            {
                ctrlPointsLists = new List<List<Point>>(1);
                ctrlPointsLists.Add(ctrlPoints);
            }
            else
            {
                ctrlPointsLists = new List<List<Point>>(1 + innersCtrlPoints.Count);
                ctrlPointsLists.Add(ctrlPoints);
                foreach (List<Point> list in innersCtrlPoints)
                    ctrlPointsLists.Add(list);
            }

            PathGeometry pg = new PathGeometry();
            foreach (List<Point> list in ctrlPointsLists)
            {
                // Step 0: check (Debug.Assert)
                Debug.Assert(list.Count % 3 == 1,
                    "public Path RenderBezier(IList<Point> ctrlPoints): number of control points is not 3n+1.");

                int n = (list.Count - 1) / 3; // Number of BezierSegments
                Debug.Assert(n > 0,
                    "public Path RenderBezier(IList<Point> ctrlPoints): at least one Bezier segment required.");

                // Step 1: Add BezierSegments to PathFigure
                PathFigure pf = new PathFigure();
                pf.StartPoint = list[0];
                for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                    pf.Segments.Add(GetBezierSegment(
                                                        list[3 * i + 1],
                                                        list[3 * i + 2],
                                                        list[3 * i + 3]
                                                    ));

                // Step 2: Add PathFigures to PathGeometry
                pg.Figures.Add(pf);
            }

            // Step 3: Add PathGemotry to GeometryGroup
            GeometryGroup gg = new GeometryGroup();
            gg.Children.Add(pg);

            // Step 4: Set GeometryGroup as Path.Data
            Path path = new Path();
            path.Data = gg;

            // Step 5: Set some Path properties
//            if (ShowOutline)
            {
                path.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                path.StrokeThickness = 1.0;
                path.StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
                path.StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round;
                path.StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
            }

            // Finally, return it
            return path;
        }

// This the evil for the performance issues (crazy memory and CPU)
        private static DropShadowEffect ShadowEffect
        {
            get
            {
                return new DropShadowEffect()
                       {
                           Color = Colors.Blue,
                           BlurRadius = 5,
                           Direction = 0,
                           ShadowDepth = 0
                       };
            }
        }

        private static BezierSegment GetBezierSegment(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3)
        {
            BezierSegment bs = new BezierSegment();
            bs.Point1 = p1;
            bs.Point2 = p2;
            bs.Point3 = p3;
            return bs;
        }

        public static readonly double[] ZoomingSteps = new double[]
        {
            1.0,
            1.5,
            2.0,
            3.0,
            4.0,
            6.0,
            8.0,
            12.0,
            16.0,
            24.0,
            32.0,
            48.0,
            64.0,
            128.0
        };
        private int index = 0;
        private void btnZoom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (index >= ZoomingSteps.Length - 1)
                return;

            ScaleTransform st = new ScaleTransform();
            st.ScaleX = st.ScaleY = ZoomingSteps[index++];

            btnZoom.Content = ZoomingSteps[index].ToString();

            mainCanvas.RenderTransform = st;
        }

        private void btnRemoveEffect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            index = 0;
            btnZoom.Content = "Zoom";
            uie.Effect = null;
            mainCanvas.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform();
        }


// If I use TextBlock as the child UIElement, then everything is okay
//            path = new TextBlock() { Text = "Text Block" };
        private void btnUseTextBlock_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mainCanvas.Children.Remove(uie);

            index = 0;
            btnZoom.Content = "Zoom";
            uie = new TextBlock() { Text = "Text Block" };

            mainCanvas.Children.Add(uie);

            uie.Effect = ShadowEffect;
            uie.CacheMode = new BitmapCache();
            mainCanvas.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried running WinDbg against your application and dumpheap the application. here is the [Result.](http://pastebin.com/Bz5Ay0FQ) Now dont worry, I dont understand half of it either. But I went a little deeper and there seem to be large amounts of arrays/lists where atleast 80% are null.

You might want to look at [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009) yourself. Here is a small [Tutorial](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/08/finding-memory-leaks-in-silverlight-with-windbg/)

I'll try to look at it in the morning if I can and I hope I've helped you atleast in the right direction

Comment: Hi Rikkos.  I tried to install the WinDbg, but I had some problem installing the Windows SDK.  As for the original problem, I think it might be Silverlight's rendering issues.  But I just don't understand why a `TextBlock` with `DropShadowEffect` is okay.

Comment: BTW, I updated the sample in case you would like to do deeper analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my trick: never use DropShadowEffect.  Create a clone of whatever you want to create a drop shadow for, put it behind the main content, and use a BlurEffect on it.  Much better performance, much better quality.  I have no idea why.

Comment: Hi Zenexer,  a clone as the shadow is also my tentative idea.  but the effect won't look so nice as the `DropShadowEffect`.  I also tried `BlurEffect`, still very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
uie.CacheMode = new BitmapCache();
```

Typically, this tells silverlight to try and cache the bitmap in memory so that the computer does not need to re-render the element in your application.

Look here for the suggested tips on silverlight performance:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189071(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: thanks for your reply. `uie.CacheMode = new BitmapCache();` here was used to test the GPU Acceleration `<param name="EnableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />`.  I have the same issue with or without this statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with how the rendering pipeline of Silverlight works. The DropShadowEffect is just a pixel shader, and pixel shaders work in Silverlight by creating a buffered copy of the image they will be applied to and then allow you to change pixel properties of the real image using the values of the buffered copy. This buffered copy is the *entire image* and is not affected by clipping. Because zooming creates a very large pre-clipped image, the pixel shader must make a physical buffered copy of a very large pre-clipped image...this is why the performance is so bad when you zoom.

The only solution I have found for this is to disable the pixel shader effect while you are zooming (or panning the zoomed image), and add it back when the image is zoomed in (or panning is complete). This way you don't incur the performance penalty of the pixel shader being applied for every frame of zooming or panning.

Comment: Hi Mike, what do you mean by `disable the pixel shader effect`? Do you mean remove the `DropShadowEffect` when zooming or panning?